# using *ngIf to toggle class by index

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I wish to toggle show a class that has `*ngFor` on it, by using the `*ngIf`, so I can toggle a `div` with its index. Here's what my code looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios; let j = index">
  <div (click)="toggle(j)" class="edit-btn">
    <p>Edit</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="show" class="input-wrapper">
      <div class="spectrum-inputs" *ngFor="let s of scenario.time; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
         <input ...>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts file:

```
public show:boolean = false;

  toggle(index) {
    this.show[index] = !this.show[index];
  }
```

I am passing the index `j` to a `(click)="toggle(j)"` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to do it this way :

```
<div *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios; let j = index">
  <div (click)="toggle(j)" class="edit-btn">
    <p>Edit</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="show === j" class="input-wrapper">
      <div class="spectrum-inputs" *ngFor="let s of scenario.time; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
         <input ...>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
public show: number;

    toggle(index) {
    if (this.show == index) {
      this.show = -1;
    }
    else {
      this.show = index;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize an array with the length of `scenarios.length` to store the state for each scenario `div` like -

```
public show = new Array(scenarios.length).fill(false);
```

And then you can do this

```
toggle(index) {
  this.show[index] = !this.show[index];
}
```

And use in HTML with `*ngIf="show[j]"`, which reads the state for that particular scenario `div`, like -

```
<div *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios; let j = index">
  <div (click)="toggle(j)" class="edit-btn">
    <p>Edit</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="show[j]" class="input-wrapper">
      <div class="spectrum-inputs" *ngFor="let s of scenario.time; let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
         <input ...>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now your `show` variable contains a single boolean value